# Get a list of available host names on LAN with Ruby

Tags: ruby, networking

Is there a way to get a list of the hostnames on a local network? I work in IT and I want to write a ruby program that lists the hostnames of the computers on the network that I can choose from to push files to.

All the computers will be on OSX 10.7/10.8.

Comment: What is your host OS? What transport? How much experience do you have in Ruby?

Comment: This sounds ambitious, there are a few parts to this program.

Comment: The base language of Ruby I am pretty comfortable with. But I can't seem to find the answer to this in Ruby, and wanted to try and avoid writing an extension in C as I am fairly rusty with C. I can really handle the rest of the app quite well, I just need to find out if it is possible to detect the hosts on the network with ruby. Every computer I am doing this in will be on OSX 10.7 or 10.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you really haven't provided a lot of detail, but heres a skeleton that should get you started.

First if you only want to do this on your network and can configure reverse DNS correctly, you can use the `resolv` library to do this:

`Resolv.getname "74.125.224.197"`

Check out more about Resolv [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv.html)

That'll get you the hostname, but of course you don't need it for file transfer.  If you have SSH listening on all the machines, you could setup all the machines to trust your key and use SSH.  You'll want [Net::SSH](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh) for this.  Alternatively you could script in the username and password but this would be a large security risk.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that. To be more specific, I work at a school and I am not in charge of imaging the computers. The guy who is won't let anyone else work on them and there are too many politics to fight that battle. What I would like to do, is write a script that is hosted on our server that shows the hosts so I can select say the 25 computers named testingcenter01-testingcenter25, then it will access the computer and copy a directory of files to a location in the system/library/applications folder. I know how to do everything but find a list of the hosts on the LAN we operate on.

Comment: And will your sysadm allow that? In a lot of places you'd get kicked off the network for violating their rules. Instead why not write something that the users install that pushes the files using their account. Your idea would never fly in a enterprise without total buy-in of management

Comment: Yes, I have complete permission to do it. We have about 950 computers in the school, most in the middle school side of it. About 3 times a year state testing gives us new tests to use that need to be copied into the directory of the program that runs the tests. I am just trying to make it easier than having to go from computer to computer to copy the files.